# VS Code Terminal not running

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, backend

when I go for console.log("hello world") my vs code terminal is not working unless I switch to java script debug terminal?
any one who know the solution please help

Comment: That’s how it’s supposed to work.

Comment: You need to install code runner extension in vscode to run your code in terminal even your `console.log("hello world");`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ===>
1 Type node in terminal
2 console.log("Hello World")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, just 2 clicks away
=> 1. Click on File
=> 2. Click on Auto Save

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Make sure that you installed Node.js After that, you need to type in Terminal window: node [whateverYourFilenameIs], click entre. //you type the word node, followed by your filename without the square brackets.

Option 2: Make sure you installed Node.js and install the VSCode extension Code Runner, restart VSCode, click on ctrl+Alt+N to run your file in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple

1. write some code example: console.log("javascript");
2. ctrl +s
3. on terminal node and your  js file name ...click enter ....and there will be no error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).